# How to Remove Infinality and use default settings?

Tags: release-loki, fonts

I followed these instructions to install Infinality on Loki

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality
```

and set the style to OSX, now the fonts look comparitively worse, how do I remove infinality and reset to the default rendering style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove it with this:

```
sudo apt-get purge fontconfig-infinality
```

And remove the PPA with this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
```